# header and trailer for sql query

Tags: c#, sql

I have a sql query which retrives the information from   SQLdatabase I need to add aheader and trailer for every batch I sent to client. I have searched but not to luck. header record should have Recordtype(1)CPC number (0000) File sequence number (001) and the trailer record should have  record type(1)total number of request(5), total court fee(),total claim amount().

```
      string stringSql1 = " SELECT distinct  " +
             "'" + comboBox6.Text + "' as Recordtype" +
             ",'" + textBox5.Text + "' as Recordtype" +

               " , space(1983) ";

          string stringSql = " SELECT distinct  " +
            "'" + comboBox6.Text + "' as RecordType" +
             " , left([Claimant Name] +'                              ',30) " +
             " , left([Claimant Address1] +'                             ',30)  " +
              " , left([Claimant Address2] +'                             ',30) as ClaimantAddress2 " +
              " , left([Claimant Address3] +'                             ',30) as ClaimantAddress3 " +
              " , left([Claimant Address4] +'                             ',30) as ClaimantAddress4 " +
    string whereClause = "";

===so on ....==================================

               string[] tempArray = new string[this.txt.Lines.Length];
                tempArray = this.txt.Lines;

                if (this.txt.Lines.Length == 0)
                {
                    return;
                }

                for (int counter = 0; counter <= tempArray.Length-1; counter++)
                {
                    if (tempArray[counter].Trim().Length > 0)
                    {
                        whereClause = whereClause + "'" + tempArray[counter] + "'" + ", ";
                    }
                }
                whereClause = whereClause.TrimEnd(' ', ',');
                whereClause = "(" + whereClause + ")";

                stringSql = stringSql.Replace("{where}", whereClause);

                myDataset = new DataSet("SQL");
                SqlConnection myConn = new SqlConnection();


                SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand();
                myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                myCommand.CommandText = stringSql;

                myCommand.Connection = myConn;

                SqlDataAdapter myAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
                myAdapter.SelectCommand = myCommand;
                myAdapter.Fill(myDataset);
```

Comment: I am just learning sql and c# guys.. sorry if have done  something terribly wrong.

Comment: What do you mean by the terms "header" and "trailer"?  Do you mean you want to create a report like structure with a header, footer and content?

Comment: yes a report like structure have the sql body but stuck with header and footer. P.Brain

Comment: Are the header and footer records with the same format as the result set?

Comment: yes they are of same of format.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want all this in a single `SELECT` statement you can add columns including aggregate information like totals, stats and stuff to a typical `SELECT`. E.G.

```
  declare @sumTotal decimal
  set @sumTotal = (SELECT SUM(ColumnName) FROM tableNameY)
--declare similar variables for total number of request(5), total court fee() and total claim amount(). 

--Create a query that outputs row data along with the info you just calculated

  select '0000' as 'CPC number', '001' as 'File sequence number', ColumnName, @sumTotal as 'total number of request', @totalCourtFeesvariable as 'total court fees'--etc...
  from tableNameX
```